# d3: use anchor elements as chart labels

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am getting started with D3 and SVG but I haven't found anything clear on how to add hyperlinks. Here is some code I have to write labels to the left of the bars in a D3 bar chart. Is there a good sample somewhere to convert these labels to hyperlinks (say objects in rangeData had an href and name/label property)? I searched around a bit but haven't gotten much further than the svg spec for adding an anchor element.

```
chart.selectAll(".bar.barLabel")
        .data(rangeData)
      .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return height(i) + barHeight(y, i) / 2; })
        .attr("dx", -20)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links) to achieve this, very similar to HTML itself. You wrap the content in the `a` element and provide the link target as the `href` attribute with `xlink` namespace.

```
chart.selectAll("a")
    .data(rangeData)
  .enter()
    .append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.href; })
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`foreignObject` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to directly embed HTML into your SVG.

Comment: I went with this approach since it appears that foreignObject is not supported in IE9 or IE10. Also, here is a very nice page I finally found that shows a concise example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html